# Add User Pool on Cross-Account Identity Pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I have a multiple AWS account w/ Cognito User Pool and another AWS account w/ Cognito Identity Pool. Is there any way to add those Cognito User Pools to Cognito Identity Pool on another AWS Account? or can I connect them via OpenID, SAML or Custom Protocol?

I'm trying to add AWS_IAM authorization on API Gateway so that all users that are authorized on said User Pool can access the API after logging in on Identity Pool.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any answers here would be helpful?